# Bent winter allow wheels, repair myself with rubber mallet?

Tags: wheels

So both of my rims currently installed in the back are bent. Since this is my winter wheels set, Someone suggested me to just try to straighten them with a rubber mallet.

Is this a good idea? Can I do it with my tires installed? Will my wheels be out of balance after that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's been my experience that trying to "bend back" cast metal causes it to weaken or break.  I've never done it with a wheel, so this isn't an "answer", but I personally wouldn't try it.  And for someone with more wheel experience than me - do they _need_ to be bent back?  If they hold air, is that slight bend really a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take them to a rim shop and have them trued. It has been my experience (yes, I've tried) in the past it will never come out right. Even when I did get it right (or so I thought) it quickly went back out of round. By taking it to a shop, they will use whatever magic is involved and get it straight ... and it'll stay that way.

Even if the tire does hold air (though, being run flats you may not be overly worried ... just joking), you will feel the thump, thump, thump of the flat spot as you are driving down the road. Since you have two bent rims, the thumping is going to be even worse.